# Java: Is it possible to compare a Class<?> object with a generic type parameter?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose i have a list of classes:

```
List<Class<?>> classes;
```

If i now take one of these classes, lets say... the second, and would want to know if it represents the String class, i would do the following:

```
classes.get(1).equals(String.class)
```

but how can i know if it represents a generic type... say T?

```
class Foo<T> {

    void someMethod(){

        System.out.println(classes.get(1).equals(T)); //error: T cannot be resolved to a variable
    }
}
```

i tried

```
T.class
(Class<T>)T
```

But nothing works. I would really like to know if this is possible, and if it is, how to achieve it.
Thanks for your attention! =)

Comment: Sorry to say, due to type erasure in the JVM, Java does not support this. That is, javac uses the type parameters during compilation but does not pass them on to the Java Runtime.  You may want to consider reading up on Scala though, it has much better type support.

Comment: When you really need this, the usual approach is to specify `Class<T> clazz` as a method parameter. See `EnumSet`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible in Java, due to type erasure (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) - `T` does not actually exist at runtime, it only exists as information for the compiler. The standard way of fixing this is to pass in a `Class<T>` from wherever `T` is reified and use that class object.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible,but instead you can provide some wrappers for your classes that will implement simple interface with one method that will return type, and then pass as generic type this interface.